# Failure in Executing MySQL query without the console

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, mysql-error-1064

I am trying to execute below query on ubuntu but every time it is giving error. Below is the query

> mysql --local-infile -u root -proot qlikviewDB -e "load data local
>   infile "/home/ubuntu/YYYY/ZZZZ.csv" into table XXXX columns terminated
>   by ',' optionally enclosed by '"' escaped by '"' lines terminated by
>   '\n' ignore 1 lines"

Getting below error

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near
>   '/home/ubuntu/YYYY/ZZZZ.csv into table
>   XXXX' at line 1

I am new to MySQL , please let me know first if we can run load data infile using -e option of mysql or not? If yes, then what is the problem in above query.

Comment: have you tried to escape the double quotes inside the `-e` argument?

Comment: try this: `mysql --local-infile -u root -proot qlikviewDB -e "load data local infile '/home/ubuntu/YYYY/ZZZZ.csv' into table XXXX columns terminated by ',' optionally enclosed by '\"' escaped by '\"' lines terminated by '\n' ignore 1 lines"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

> mysql --local-infile -u root -proot qlikviewDB -e "load data local
>   infile '/home/ubuntu/YYYY/ZZZZ.csv' into table XXXX columns terminated
>   by ',' optionally enclosed by '\"' escaped by '\"' lines terminated by
>   '\n' ignore 1 lines"

Comment: Just Awesome!!!! Worked like a charm :)..